# Logout button not working on mobile devices

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. Ok, so I have a really weird bug that's been really tricky to figure out. The logout button on my app works fine unless you're using a mobile device. Here's the error I'm getting (again keep in mind it's only on my mobile device):

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/salir"
```

Here's some code:

application_controller.rb

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def require_current_user
  current_user
  redirect_to root_path unless @current_user
end
```

_header.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to '<i class="fa-power-off"></i> Salir'.html_safe, salir_es_path, method: :delete, class: "text-danger" %></li>
```

session_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  reset_session
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

routes.rb

```
root 'providers#index'



localized do


  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy],
    path_names: { new: "ingresa", destroy: 'salir' }


  get '/login', to: 'sessions#login', as: 'login'
  get '/salir', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'salir'
end
```

Comment: Share your `routes.rb` contents in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursory look at the routes file would seem to indicate that the `get '/salir'` line is your problem.

Note that your error indicates that there is no route matching DELETE (versus the entry in routes for `get`).

My sense is the following change would help:

```
# from
get '/salir', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'salir'
# to 
match '/salir', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'salir', via: :delete
```

Comment: Thanks Craig! That totally worked. If you're ever in Peru I'll make sure to buy you a beer!

Comment: Haha! You're on freddy :)!